# Typescript loses generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a TS fuction that manipulates an object, containing arrays. The result works, but the TS compiler throws errors.

Here is the simplified code:

```ts
interface Cat{
  id: number
  isMeowing: boolean
}

interface Dog{
  id: number
  isBarking: boolean
}

interface Animals {
  Cats: Cat[]
  Dogs: Dog[]
}

const animalList = {
  Cats: [],
  Dogs: []
} as Animals

function addAnimals<T extends keyof Animals>(key: T, newItems: Animals[T]){
  const existingItems = animalList[key]
  for(const newItem of newItems){
    const existingItem = existingItems.find((ei) => ei.id === newItem.id)
    if (existingItem) {
          Object.assign(existingItem, newItem)
        } else {
          existingItems.push(newItem)
        }
    }
}

addAnimals('Cats', [{id: 1, isMeowing: true}])

console.log(animalList)
```

[And a playground, with the errors.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzAbwFDOcAEwC5kQBXAWwCNpd8BnAWQgHsB3UAcxKpZYBsIcENgC+2bKEixEKACItOOPIRLlqtFfQBCcKAGsuPPoOFiJU6PCTIAgiGAU4-esmVoM9EujABtALp0CpxeyMEB5tgILCD0YMjCjs4AMsBxyAC8bnQ+oQEANEGKeYGiCa72SS4SMGQgCGDAMQkEBJVOLgA8ACrIEAAekCAErvoQAJ4sMHYOHfQAfAAUY+Mk3fmkEGwAkpAUoe3O9L7d-gCU7tGx8QNpjSCcuxD7mQmzKXe+K4F4MCxQiyu6RAWyeFGQU02Oz29AudDwQJu-TuXDBr1ucVRMIAdDBQARFosIMAzpl5n1gNjCJkMlkQdDnlSCGd4fhpkTkZiHmDSe48Pz+QB5KgAKwgDWxcHo9GAnBAHJR3L2G3pPNZArKEBcKD5Av5GPujxxAAcyPQABaLVV7Fl6-niDWROCtQ4uRYAcly7o2vkwqmQAEYNmlmOwjMgwFAyBBROcJECBBBsfxFItEh1UnEzkA)

The generic function should know that its **either** working with cats **or** dogs, but it loses the generic: `existingItems` is typed as `Cat[] | Dog[]`, and calling the `find()` function is illegal. Is it possible to write a function that does the same, and is valid in TS?

Comment: In order for the compiler to follow your logic you need to refactor to a *distributive object type* as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NB4yzW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks! It's working, and is an acceptable answer to the original question. But:

1. If the Animals type is coming from an external source (api generator), is there a solution that involves the function only?

2. I still don't understand why. Does the same occur in statically typed languages too?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373

Until it is fixed, I would just use the `as` type assertion to make the array into `Animal[]` temporarily, so you can use `find` on it.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373 was [closed as fixed today](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373#event-9262876032).